# Can I use MKL functions with user allocated data?

Tags: intel-mkl, intel-ipp

Is there a problem using MKL with user (non 64 bit aligned) allocated data ?

I'm trying to use MKL function

```
vcMulByConj(...)
```

with continues memory allocated using OpenCV mat object. (with I believe it's implemented using "new" c++ operation)

I frequently receive an access violation exception.

I'm aware that MKL would work with 64 bit aligned allocation

```
void* datta = MKL_malloc(n*n*sizeof(double),64);
```

I'm aware of the performance vulnerability, albeit, can I use my own unaligned memory to use MKL functions?

Is there any problem with my memory model ?

I would ask the same question for IPP functions

---

Update:

Both MKL and IPP are aligned to 64 bit, Can I use the same memory allocation mechanize for both MKL and IPP library calls ?

(Lets say using ippiMalloc() for both libraries)

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Using aligned memory is a recommendation which may improve the performance, but it is not a requirement. MKL functions generally work correctly on both aligned and unaligned data.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/528558

For IPP, this is also true. See the last Q&A in the following link.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/performance-tools-for-software-developers-memory-function-faq

Comment: Thank you, both MKL and IPP are aligned to 64 bit, Can I use the same memory allocation mechanize for both MKL and IPP (using ippiMalloc() for both libraries )? I updated my question